# How to convert dataframe rows with cells containing multiple lines to separate columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have an existing pandas dataframe with many rows that looks like TABLE-1.
Each row has the same number of lines per cell. I.e. c1 has 4 lines, c2 has 2 lines, c3 has two lines, etc... And some have only a single line.

TABLE-1:

| c1 | c2 | c3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| "City of Pflugerville\nNew Residential Permits\n3/8/2020 12:00:00 AM thru 3/8/2021 12:00:00 AM\nCity", | "20-48935\n3/21/2020 12:00:00 AM", | "Residential\nResidential Building" |

I'm wanting to have a column for each line. As what is shown in TABLE-2:

| c1 | c2 | c3 | c4 | c5 | c6 | c7 | c8 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| City of Pflugerville | New Residential Permits | 3/8/2020 12:00:00 AM thru 3/8/2021 12:00:00 AM | City | 20-48935 | 3/21/2020 12:00:00 AM | Residential | Residential Building |

I have found plenty of examples showing how to create new rows from multiple lines within a cell but not new columns.

I've trying to do this with df.iterrows() and split() but not able to get the correct results.
Please point me in the right direction. THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

You can do str split and then rename the columns

```
df = pd.concat([df[i].str.split('\n', expand=True) for i in df.columns], axis=1)
df.columns = ['c{}'.format(i) for i in range(1,9)]
```

```
                     c1                       c2                                              c3    c4        c5                     c6           c7                    c8
0  City of Pflugerville  New Residential Permits  3/8/2020 12:00:00 AM thru 3/8/2021 12:00:00 AM  City  20-48935  3/21/2020 12:00:00 AM  Residential  Residential Building
```